# How to update G++ with MinGW

Tags: c++, g++

I need g++ 4.9 or 4.8 and I only have 4.4 in my MinGW. How can I update it, because I have the latest MinGW on Windows. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, this link may be more useful: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do a fresh install. First you need to delete the MinGW folder and all of its contents. (In my case it is located in C:\MinGW) Then you need to download the installer from http://www.mingw.org/. The link is located by the right upper corner. After setting it up you need to go to the MinGW Installation manager and select mingw32-gcc-g++. Last you need to go to the installation menu and click in the Apply Changes option.